# Can i develop helix projects in sitecore 7+

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, helix

Hi I am exploring helix principles and going through the habit project. Since we have got the mvc support from sitecore 6.6, can i develop helix projects from sitecore 7+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helix isn’t about a version. It is about the application of SOLID Component design to Sitecore. In short, yes, you can use Helix principles in all versions of Sitecore. Also, you can, and should (must?) use SOLID principles in all the software you build. Sitecore or otherwise.

FWIW, SOLID Component development doesn’t require any particular platform. It is equally applicable to Java, C#, ASPNET WebForms, MVC, WebAPI, or PHP.

These are merely development principles you should use to write better software.